# Find mysql table by matching record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have four tables: `Couriers`, `Cars`, `Planes` and `Boats`.

The table Couriers has columns like: price, destination, etc.

The last three tables are different types of couriers with different columns proper to the type of courier (e.g. cars has the column cylinders). However, all four tables have the column `IdCourier`, which links the type of courier (and its properties) with its price, destination, etc.

I know the `IdCourier` of a courier and want to get its price and to know if it's a car, plane or boat.

What Mysql query should I use?

Does this structure of tables make sense?

Comment: Is it possible for `IdCourier` to be duplicated in `Cars`, `Planes`, or `Boats` (i.e. is both a car and boat)?

Comment: No, it isn't duplicated.

Comment: In the Cars, Planes and Boats tables is there a column that identifies the type of courier. Or is there such a column in the Couriers table?

Comment: Each table has a column IdCourier. For example: Cars has IdCourier, and Cylinders, Boats has IdCourier and Knot, Planes has IdCourier and Jet, and Couriers has IdCourier and Price.

Comment: I'm thinking about using IF() functions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways that you can do this.  If you kept that table structure, you could so something like to keep it down to 1 query:

```
SELECT `price`, 'car' as `mytype`
FROM Couriers 
JOIN Cars ON (Couriers.Id = Cars.IdCourier)
WHERE Cars.IdCourier = ?

UNION

SELECT `price`, 'plane' as `mytype`
FROM Couriers 
JOIN Planes ON (Couriers.Id = Planes.IdCourier)
WHERE Planes.IdCourier = ?

UNION

SELECT `price`, 'boat' as `mytype`
FROM Couriers 
JOIN Boats ON (Couriers.Id = Boats.IdCourier)
WHERE Boats.IdCourier = ?;
```

But this is rather expensive.  Instead, I would personally create a 5th table called like CouriersTypes with the fields **IdCourier**, **IdType**, and **Type**. Index the **IdCourier** for fast searching.  **This example assumes that a Courier could fit any OR all of the types (car, plane, boat).**  Now your query becomes:

```
SELECT `price`, `Type` 
FROM Couriers
JOIN CouriersTypes ON (Couriers.Id = CouriersTypes.IdCourier)
WHERE IdCourier = ?;
```

Your result would be much faster for large amounts of data.  **IF** a courier can only do one type, then forget that example and just add the **idType** and **Type** to the Couriers table and query it directly.

```
SELECT `price`, `Type` 
FROM Couriers
WHERE Id = ?;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'll go with the last option. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The structure makes sense.  The type of query would depend on what you are planning to do with the data.

If you want to retrieve a specific car from Cars you would use something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Courier INNER JOIN Cars ON Cars.IdCourier = Courier.IdCourier WHERE Courier.IdCourier = ?
```

You could always alias the tables to make the syntax easier to write.  Also, the WHERE clause would only be used if you want to SELECT a specific record.

If you can post the create table statements it would help.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know if my courier is a car. I only have its IdCourier and want to know what kind of courier is it.

Comment: Will The Cars, Boats and Planes tables have the same number of columns?  If so you could join a subquery that uses a union for the Cars, Boats and Planes tables to combine them together and join to the Courier table.  The only issue is that you wouldn't know which table your result came from.

Comment: They don't have the same number of columns.

Comment: Post your database code and tell us what your query needs to do.